# dpkg-buildpackage reapplies patches to debian/rules

Tags: linux, debian

I'm trying to build libc6 with a custom prefix by modifying the `prefix=/usr` line in `debian/rules`. However, this fails because the patch is applied multiple times. Curiously, patching *another* file does not result in the same error. I've distilled the failure down to this script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -exuo pipefail

work_dir=$(mktemp -d)
cd "$work_dir"

apt-get source libc6
cd eglibc-2.19

cat <<'PATCH' > ../set-prefix.diff
Index: eglibc-2.19/debian/rules
===================================================================
--- eglibc-2.19.orig/debian/rules>2022-03-01 17:27:53.068299816 -0800
+++ eglibc-2.19/debian/rules>-2022-03-01 17:27:53.068299816 -0800
@@ -85,7 +85,7 @@
 # Default setup
 EGLIBC_PASSES ?= libc

-prefix=/usr
+prefix=/new/prefix
 bindir=$(prefix)/bin
 datadir=$(prefix)/share
 localedir=$(prefix)/lib/locale
PATCH

cat <<'PATCH' > ../change-readme.diff
Index: eglibc-2.19/README
===================================================================
--- eglibc-2.19.orig/README     2013-10-18 14:33:25.000000000 -0700
+++ eglibc-2.19/README  2022-03-02 17:00:49.954759733 -0800
@@ -1,5 +1,7 @@
 This directory contains the Embedded GNU C Library (EGLIBC).

+Add a line.
+
 EGLIBC is a variant of the GNU C Library (GLIBC) that is designed to
 work well on embedded systems. EGLIBC strives to be source and binary
 compatible with GLIBC. EGLIBC's goals include reduced footprint,
PATCH

quilt import ../change-readme.diff -P any/change-readme.diff
quilt push

quilt import ../set-prefix.diff -P any/set-prefix.diff
quilt push

dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -S -ai386
```

Here's the relevant output I'm seeing:

```
 dpkg-source -b eglibc-2.19
dpkg-source: info: using options from eglibc-2.19/debian/source/options: --compression=xz
dpkg-source: info: using source format `3.0 (quilt)'
dpkg-source: info: building eglibc using existing ./eglibc_2.19.orig.tar.xz
patching file debian/rules
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
dpkg-source: info: fuzz is not allowed when applying patches
dpkg-source: info: if patch 'any/set-prefix.diff' is correctly applied by quilt, use 'quilt refresh' to update it
dpkg-source: error: LC_ALL=C patch -t -F 0 -N -p1 -u -V never -g0 -E -b -B .pc/any/set-prefix.diff/ --reject-file=- < eglibc-2.19.orig.yzNU0V/debian/patches/any/set-prefix.diff gave error exit status 1
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -b eglibc-2.19 gave error exit status 2
```

Commenting out the `quilt import` and `quilt push` commands for `set-prefix.diff` results in success but of course the prefix isn't updated like I want. It seems like patches are getting applied multiple times which is fine for most files but not `debian/rules` - maybe these patches are applied on a fresh source directory but the `debian/` directory is left in tact?

What is the recommended way to build libc6 with a custom prefix without having `dpkg-buildpackage`/`dpkg-source` fail due to reapplying patches?

Comment: PS: do not do it on a system library. You can have parallel versions without problem. In any case, `debian/` directory is special and should not be patched. Just change it. Note: debian ignore (discard) the upstream `debian/` directory, so it create a patch to create all files from existing data (which you have modified), and then you tell to reapply again.

Comment: And note: you are modifying essential packages, so you should known very well all internals because all other packages have some implicit expectation. In short: start experimenting with less fundamental libraries, until you get the internal (possibly very few people know the internal, without need to test and check carefully many sources)

Comment: Updating `debian/rules` without using `quilt` worked. Thanks! If you want to submit this as an answer I can accept it otherwise I can submit an answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `debian/rules` directory is special [citation needed] and shouldn't be patched using the usual `quilt` commands. You can modify them directly before building the package or use the `patch` command (`patch -p1` in this case).